# Openbox: desktop, autostart, new aplications installation issue

Tags: openbox

My computer is very old so in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I am running 'openbox', which is minimalist (therefore it makes my computer to run smoother).

But I have some doubts/issues about openbox

**1)** How do I put desktop icons on openbox?

**2)** How do I set a wallpaper on openbox?

**3)** How do I set to autostart 'xfce4-panel' (which gives me a more friendly visual to my openbox)? I already have xfce4-panel installed on the computer.

**4)** When I try to install an app using Ubuntu Software Center it is said that I do not have privileges do install it (but there is only 1 account in Ubuntu, which obviously is the administrator one)

Could anybody help me with these?

Thank you all.

Comment: PCManFM is a file manager that can controll the desktop for you. It will render any icons (.desktop files really) you put into ~/Desktop (or you can set other directory as root, in my case, the home folder), it will also allow you to set a background. Tint2 is indeed a great taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

Openbox is not necessarily better or faster then Xubuntu, kubuntu, or lubuntu.

Lubuntu uses openbox and adds a number of tools to do most of what you ask (lxappearance, lxpanel, etc).

Xubuntu and kubuntu do not use that much more in terms of resources and I find heavy apps such as firefox or libreoffice do not start or perform faster in openbox.

gnome (gnome-shell and unity) are the exception as they are more demanding of your video card.

See http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/desktop-environments-ram-use/

There is more then a window manager at play when you switch to openbox or fluxbox as most of the DE run services in the background that make things easier, so it is a trade off.

If you stay with openbox, you may wish to look at light weight alternates.

My suggestion for a panel is tint2.

[image]

Suggestions for additional apps include nitrogen (to set bg image). Other tools you might wish to use include lxappearacne (to set themes and icons) and obconf .

Light weight apps whenever possible - I find chromium is faster then firefox for example. You might try midori ;)

Comment: No, thank's. I would like to keep using Openbox inside Ubuntu.

Comment: OK, openbox + tint2 is, IMO, the way to go, This is how !# does it. At any rate, see http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Autostart